# Using values from outside onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

I have an array of Spinners, hours[]. I am setting it up in a loop. When an item is selected, I need to take it and insert it into a database table, so I need the value of the loop counter in the onItemSelected() function. How do I do this? Here is the code:

```
for(int i=0; i<36; i++)
    {
        hours[i].setAdapter(adapter);
        hours[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int x, long l)
                    {
                        String in=String.valueOf(adapterView.getSelectedItem());
                        DBHelper db=new DBHelper(AcceptTimetable.this, null, null, 1);
                        db.changeHour((int)Math.ceil(i/6), (i+1)%6, new Subject(in));
                        //need to use i here, but it's giving an error
                        db.close();
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg)
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                });
    }
```

Also, I'm not sure String in=String.valueOf(adapterView.getSelectedItem()); is correct. Can anyone tell me how to get the selected value from the Spinner? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
for(int i=0; i<36; i++)
    {
        Log.v("Select Items in Spinner",hours[i].getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
    }
```

From that log you can see the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.
Easier, but less efficient is to include `hours[i].setPrompt(String.valueOf(i))` and then retrieve that value inside the listener via `int index = Int.parse(((Spinner) adapterView).getPrompt())`.

The more efficient way is to extend the Spinner in a separate class and add an index attribute and keep the index in it.

EDIT: the `getSelectedItem()` method returns an object whose type matches the one you specified when initializing the adapter you've bound to your [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I have updated my code, and hours is a 2D array. So I need to pass two values, i and j. Can I somehow do this using setPrompt()? Or is there any other way to do it? I didn't understand how to do this by extending Spinner

Comment: I made a class called Spin, extending Spinner, and added two variables i and j. I changed my code accordingly, but now it gives me an error at 
hours[0][0]=(Spin)findViewById(R.id.ttmon1);
saying "Error inflating class Spin"
How do i fix this?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't logged in for two days. Within you Spin class you need to explicitly write a conversion constructor which converts a `View` object to `Spin` object